# How to open popup only instead of page when tab bar (bottom bar) item tap in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Whenever we click any item of tab bar(bottom bar) i want to open only popup not whole page. popup will open on any previously selected tab bar item. For example We have 5 tab bar item.

- tb item 1 (Page1)
- tb item 2 (Page2)
- tb item 3 (No page but popup only)
- tb item 4 (Page4)
- tb item 5 (Page5)

If i am on tb item 1 (Page1) and click on tb item 3 it will open popup over tb item 1 (Page1).

[image]

I [checked this plugin](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) but it is not allowing to do this.

Comment: And what's the content of the popup? for example, does it have any kind of form like in the plugin you referenced

Comment: You could create your own tab bar using a grid, and then do what ever you like with those buttons

Comment: @Viral Are you using Xamarin Forms Shell? If yes then you can Control the navigation when user clicks on that particular tab and open the popup instead!

If you can control the Navigating event from Navigation and Cancel the current navigation event and show the popup that's the way to go. Hope it helps you to research on that direction.

Comment: For tab bar I used "TabbedPage" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page Is there any way we can click any tab item but restrict to open page or tab item without any page. is that possible ?

Comment: No, you have to use a custom tabbar.

Comment: Did you get any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

`TabbedPage` should have pages as children by default.
I am assuming you want to remain on same page when tb item 3 is tapped. Be it tb item 1 tb item 2 tb item 4 ...

Instead of that you can have a single page with 5 icons at the bottom of the page.
And include OnTapped gestures for all 5 items, for item 3 call Pop up , while for others navigate to respective page.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App1.Views.PageX">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Label Text="Page content" />
            </StackLayout>
            <Grid VerticalOptions="End">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ImageButton Source="tab_feed.png"
                             Grid.Column="0"
                             Clicked="ImageButton1_Clicked" />
                <ImageButton Source="tab_feed.png"
                             Grid.Column="1"
                             Clicked="ImageButton2_Clicked" />
                <ImageButton Source="tab_feed.png"
                             Grid.Column="2"
                             Clicked="ImageButton3_Clicked" />
                <ImageButton Source="tab_feed.png"
                             Grid.Column="3"
                             Clicked="I mageButton4_Clicked" />
                <ImageButton Source="tab_feed.png"
                             Grid.Column="4"
                             Clicked="ImageButton5_Clicked" />
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

and page navigation

```cs
private async void ImageButton1_Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync (new ItemPage1 ());
}
```

for popup

```cs
private async void ImageButton3_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Rg.Plugins.Popup.Contracts.IPopupNavigation.PushAsync(new MyPopupPage(), true);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Sorry i am not able to use this way because app is already developed and I am adding this module to app. For tab bar I used "TabbedPage" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page.

Is there any way we can click any tab item but restrict to open page or tab item without any page. is that possible ?